# How to consume one API endpoint which requires data from another API endpoint (dog.ceo)?

Tags: javascript, async-await

how to consume from one api with another api.

```
var url_1 = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';

fetch(url_1)
     .then( response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
const breeds = data.message;
var arr = [];

for (var b in breeds) {
      arr.push({
           breed : b,
           subBreeds : [
             breeds[b][0]
           ],
          images : [{
            url: ''
          }]
      })
  }
```

I also have this other api, from where I extract the images of each breed of dog, but here you need the variable that would be the name of the dog's breed.

```
var url_2 = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breed/{breed_name}/images';

fetch(url_2)
   .then( response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
      const images = data.message;
      var arr_images = [];  

   for (var i in images) {
        arr_images.push({
          images : [{
            url: images[i]
          }]    
        })
    }
```

So what I don't know, how can I join to send the name of the dog's breed to the second api to consume it?

And how can I join the arrangement of the images with the arrangement above?

it should be something like this

```
{ "breed": "Hound", 
  "subBreeds": [ 
    "subBreedA", 
    "subBreedB", 
    "subBreedC" 
   ], 
  "images":[
     {"url":"http://some.url.com"},
    {"url":"http://some.other.url"}
   ]
}
```

I hope I have been clear, thanks for your help, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split it up into separate functions so that you can focus on one part at a time. Then, combine them to get all of the data that you want. In this way, you can also re-use each function in case you want to use the data in a different way:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEBMHsHMDoGMCmlQEEAKBJAsAKDwC4CeADoqACIwaYBKiAziZAHYOIA8AKgHygC8oAN55QoALaMGAQ2iIAXKC4BuUaAYFpBAK4NFGgE4BLFtFW4AvubzAAVLdG3QmcbPIBVWgBkGjx5Uh4PVAACwICEj0QKDgkSGAYgFppEiMEwO1JFk0CI1ZgACMDRERwfwBRFnBmEwJFMIio9NjkYBS0opLwYCFO0otgI1c5X1xQJ0rqyFr68Mj5aJgEVvbC4tKevvABoQZtAoB9LYGht1Hx4EJScipoFzOBdQJjUwBtAF1rXDsHMacAZX2iS2oBY0kk51+4wCQVmjQWzWW8SSqyg8EyiGyWjyLGAewKwPWZT+oEmNWycPmixa8VWW02RIGABsjBpHJdcMQyKBAQUAEJErysgiPQwmaAfL4-fyoJlMiAwUBbSH+Kiw0JzJoxJHNZKpdLorI5HEc6Fk6YUjXw6k6ulEhjAFkaNpy9lXbkCrpCjSPERjUCvLb6Z7i96KXme0regjmKx4PDSBhEFjwUAAM20KdyrHTiAI8BCt1QqXoeyZIu4PAAFO10FoQsGXtAAJSKdAGSDiVmcXjCNTwVg+4pMQfkQTSADu0iMIrTeYLVYABg0qYi4m19QASIS1+sWRfN8xiIxp0BVgCEw+YbEQsEgAGtm6ACCEOxPQYh3+UDB2DEvS9e7CgpAIoAPIANJntuV6jrAGhaLoFjNgeR6gAObAiuAWjSI8k7TiKME3rAABWDCsFWT6JgE0A0ABo6VqhJ5nlhmhwTkuigOe-CCAA5Hs8BIAwDA8U+L5vh+X4-pAf48XRN7ASK-GCQwGZMiJqHFDoBgsBA2GwBCMhyLG8a4ImyaphmWY4rm+YhJG4AMGeT5+mImnaNpNkFkWJaMNo5YcPZ0bVjxyqOsKLpqYeeAWCZZkpummbwNmOlzrZEb2meQZPE2zlqG5HmpV51A+WWBAcOlXrCtWi70tuxxhRoKHRbFSbxZZSXWYVIT3CMmVEo24oADTqPs9kAPwDaYuX+vlKXzoWxVGKWfllbcPWMNVtW9Iy274vZoBjaAi7ALto2MouoCKDxPEnMMjBNZYJlcjcMD2ZgLBpiggguUq-XZeKqF7fa4ZnZVGiMXdwRCKA7lMpN0CgBYkrRV8cUWYlyWeQt0AUNhTlth2XbsBwtxvR9kAfHwP3oT6yq4VOM5Y-ZDAURpebuTp7adt2sDSHKVagQUxGIElsCYiGjBVsqzb6SkNatamVaBkSw1A10DDvE+-B8FWP1iFsg1qGIaulAwhv+sekOKDWDOzvN60s1szYy64JBVrDAg60IsNIc25tiL7UWPfguDy+ZTme32-o05hMC45o9P4Vjtzx9IrP9oOkBMreTIwFWABS-ygQAcmxTYnkQVYxKnzuxs2rNAA)

```js
// dog.ceo API

async function fetchDogApiResult (apiPath) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/${apiPath}`);
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Response not OK (${response.status})`);
  const data = await response.json();
  if (data.status !== 'success') throw new Error('Response not successful');
  return data.message;
}

async function fetchBreeds () {
  return fetchDogApiResult('breeds/list/all');
}

async function fetchSubBreeds (breed) {
  return fetchDogApiResult(`breed/${breed}/list`);
}

async function fetchImages (breed, subBreed) {
  return fetchDogApiResult(`breed/${breed}${subBreed ? `/${subBreed}` : ''}/images`);
}

async function fetchDogData () {
  const breeds = await fetchBreeds();
  return Promise.all(Object.entries(breeds).map(async ([breed, subBreeds]) => ({
    breed,
    subBreeds,
    images: (await fetchImages(breed)).map(url => ({url})),
  })));
}

(async () => {
  const dogData = await fetchDogData();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dogData));
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` for call second api in second `then` of first api, after you get data from second api, you can use `for` loop for them. like this

```
        var url_1 = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';

    fetch(url_1)
         .then( response => response.json())
         .then(async data => {
    const breeds = data.message;
    const resUrl2 = await fetch(url_2)
    const dataUrl2 = await resUrl2.json()
    var arr = [];

    for (var b in breeds) {
          arr.push({
               breed : b,
               subBreeds : [
                 breeds[b][0]
               ],
              images : [{
                url: ''
              }]
          })
      }

    const images = dataUrl2.message;
          var arr_images = [];  

       for (var i in images) {
            arr_images.push({
              images : [{
                url: images[i]
              }]    
            })
        }
    })
```